# Anti-slip (ice, water) mat for outdoor stair treads?

Tags: outdoor, stairs

I used composite decking to build my stair treads and it gets slippery, especially when water freezes over during winter. I need five of something that is 6' long and 6" deep to provide traction.

- Adhesive safety mats are garbage and peel off easily. These are meant for indoors.
- Home Depot sells short rubber strips (36" x 6") for $15 ea. 5 steps would cost me $150.

Anybody tried laying down carpet tape ($10) and screwing down some [Lowe's Mineral Roofing Roll](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Owens-Corning-3-ft-W-x-36-ft-L-100-sq-ft-Onyx-Black-Roll-Roofing/3005569) ($50; 3'x 36')?

I tested out the traction and it's decent. The little rocks don't wear too much when you step on them. I just bought a roll and haven't cut into it yet because I'm concerned this stuff tears easily (hoping the carpet tape would prevent it from flaking).

I'm gonna try it out tonight but was wondering how other folks have solved this issue.

Comment: I've often used standard shingles on wood stairs...  one downside is that the shingles tend to trap the moisture onto the surface of the treads and they rot quicker.  Composite treads might not have this problem given they are mostly plastic.

Comment: chicken wire works well on wooden stairs, dunno about plastic ones.

Comment: I'd be worried about black ice on the asphalt.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it and it works well. Carpet tape was necessary and should be applied liberally, especially to cover the edges. I didn't think to do it this time but the entire backside should be taped to prevent tearing.

Cut the roofing roll with large shears. Use #10 3/4"-1" screws (drywall screws works too, albeit will rust) to secure the two sides of the strip (I recommend washers for a better hold since the head can easily sink into the strip and provide no holding).